# How do I convert stereoscopic 3D photos (.sjpg, side-by-side, interlaced) to Facebook-compatible depth-map+stereo pair .heic 3D?

Tags: photos, 3d, image-conversion

[*.heic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) is the "new jpg" being pushed by Apple, Samsung, etc. It is a improved image format.

Facebook not only supports glTF 3D models, but also now supports iPhone 7 & iPhone 8 3D photos, which are depth-map + stereo pair *.heic's

[image]

How can I convert existing side-by-side 3D stereoscopic images (without the depth map) to this new format facebook  recognizes? It would involve generating a depth map and repackaging the binary file.

[At least in theory this is possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCgCkNqJvEw)

I've been taking 3D photos for years using dual-lens, mirror-lens techniques, and would love to share my library of photos with my friends. Also there is a vast library of historic stereoscopic 3D photos, going back to the 1800s! It would be lovely to generate a depth map from these and package them in a format that could be uploaded for the masses. As it is, it requires a google cardboard or various cross-eye / anaglyph techniques to view.

Comment: Someone has done this via mobile it looks like: https://www.facebook.com/hangingpixels/posts/2040850755974982

Comment: What is ‘‘heic’’?  I don’t need a 4000-word technical explanation, but when I see an unfamiliar term in a question title, I like to find it at least mentioned in the question body.

Comment: @Scott Added an explanation of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muttyan's [Stereo Photo Maker](http://stereo.jpn.org/eng/stphmkr/index.html) will do it via Ugo Capeto's [Depth Map Generator](https://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/p/software.html) [DMAG5](https://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/2014/05/depth-map-automatic-generator-5-dmag5.html)

Approximate steps [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEBMjHMfoIs):

- run stphmkre.exe
- Select stereo pair
- Use auto align tool to get it pretty
- Ctrl Shift D to select Depth map creation
- MUST use [dmag5_9b.zip](http://stereo.jpn.org/eng/stphmkr/makedm/) extracted folder or it won't find dmag
- You can correct the depth map in the depth map menu
- Then export via Depth map save as facebook compatible 2D image + depth map pair (which is just two jpgs, one with `*_depth.jpg`)